# On Flutter iOS, I can't upload to Firebase Storage because of 400 errors

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm having an issue uploading files to Firebase storage using Flutter. It only happens on iOS.

```
cancelFetcher Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 34, bytes = 0x55706c6f 61642068 61732061 6c726561 ... 6e616c69 7a65642e }, data_content_type=text/plain; charset=utf-8}
```

I can download files, but not upload. Android works fine so it's not the backend. Firestore works perfectly on both platforms.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: The issue must be with the Storage permissions or the security rules, please check both.

Comment: The security rules shouldn't matter. It works on Android which is the same code base.

Comment: Then, can you check if this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68796375/15774177) helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the contentType and the rules were preventing it from uploading.

```
  final metadata = SettableMetadata(
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  );

  await storage.ref(path).putData(data, metadata);
```